# jQuery : Dynamic table rows not working with events

Tags: jquery

I am coding a HTML table of products. There are lot of columns with lot of jQuery events (change, click, etc) attached to form elements (button, text, select) inside each column. They work perfectly fine.

The last column contains "add" link which makes an AJAX callback to a URL that adds a new row dynamically inside the table.

```
$('table td .addrow').live('click', function() {
  var cur_obj = this;
  $.ajax({
   url: 'product/addrow',
   success: function(data) {
    $(cur_obj).parent().parent().after(data);
   }
  });
 });
```

The row is getting added dynamically but none of the jQuery events are working even though they work fine with the preloaded rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or the [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) jQUery functions

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be separating your .live() usage from the add link? Sounds like you want the click(), change(), etc events to work the same on all rows so add .live() events to them, something like:

```
$('table td').live('click', function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

So the .live() call makes sure you new rows are add to the eventhandlers. If you have an addrow element on each new row that you add then your original code looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

`$('table').delegate('td', 'click', function() {
  //do stuff
});`